# Creating Homepage Ad Campaign On Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

When I try to create a homepage ad campaign I get this error: "You must only create marketplace ads in marketplace locations"

I guess Facebook does not create campaign as homepage ad, therefore it puts me in a position where I am trying to create homepage ad in a marketplace campaign.

I am adding lifetime_imps in campaign create request and I do not know any other way to differentiate homepage ad campaign from marketplace campaign.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/premium-via-api/ - which part of this isn't working?

Comment: cannot create ad groups in the campaign? how can i make sure create campaign is a homepage ad campaign not a marketplace campaign?

Comment: I meant, what are you doing **based on the documentation** which is not working, and what error are you receiving? i.e what parameters are you specifying in your API calls, are you selecting the correct locations in accordance with the documentation, using a campaign specifically for the homepage ads, etc?